# Pseudo-random number generation in MEX C

Tags: c, matlab, random, mex, standard-library

By definition, the function `srand(seed)` seeds the random number generator used by `rand()`. If it is not called, the default seed is `1` according to [the documentation](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.13.html#srand). Consider the following MEX code `test.c`:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    srand(1);
    mexPrintf("%lf\n",(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
}
```

It always returns the same random number when called from Matlab:

```
>> mex test.c
>> test
0.001251
>> test
0.001251
>> test
0.001251
```

Consider the following code `test2.c`, where `srand()` is not called before the random number generation:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mexPrintf("%lf\n",(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
}
```

This code returns the same random number at the first call, but different numbers are returned for every subsequent call:

```
>> mex test2.c
>> test2
0.001251
>> test2
0.563585
>> test2
0.193304
```

Given the default behavior of `srand()`, I don't understand why omitting `srand(1)` yields different random numbers at every call. In fact, compiling and running `test2.c` outside Matlab (with `printf` instead of `mexPrintf`, `int main()` instead of `void mexFunction(...)`, etc.) always returns the same random number, as would be expected.

Why does the MEX behave like this?

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but using the "built-in" random number generators, such as `rand`, `irand`, and `drand48`, is almost always a bad choice – particularly for any scientific computing or research. See rule #1 [here](http://cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.jones/GoodPracticeRNG.pdf) (PDF). Matlab's default PRNG, [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) is freely available in [C, C++, and many other languages](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/eversions.html) and is often faster as well.

Comment: @horchler: if you really wanted to use MATLAB's Mersenne Twister PRNG from MEX, you could link against `libmwmathrng.dll` and call the undocumented C++ function `mrRandu` (its signature: `void mrRandu(double *arr, size_t len);`). This will share the same underlying RNG state vector, so calling it will advance the internal random stream used by MATLAB. [From what I understand](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/119520#302137), MATLAB uses the same reference implementation you mentioned (only with a slight modification to exclude zero value from `rand` output)

Comment: There are of course other versions of this function inside the DLL `libmwmathrng.dll` matching `rand`/`randi`/`randn` in all their variations. Just use "Dependency Walker" to browse the list of exported C/C++ functions. But as with any undocumented function, it is not guaranteed to remain there in all MATLAB releases (mine is R2014a). The safe (documented) way is to use [`mexCallMATLAB`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html) and call `rand` from MATLAB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MEX-files are shared libraries (with a special entry function `mexFunction`) that are dynamically loaded by MATLAB when executed. They remain loaded in memory unless you clear them.

#### Example:

Initially the MEX-file is not loaded (ignore this other MEX-file from another toolbox):

```
>> [~,X] = inmem('-completenames')
X = 
    'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\slvnv\reqmgt\reqmgt.mexw64'
```

Now we call the MEX function:

```
>> test2
0.001251
>> test2
0.563585
>> [~,X] = inmem('-completenames')
X = 
    'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\slvnv\reqmgt\reqmgt.mexw64'
    'C:\Users\Amro\Desktop\test2.mexw64'    % <-- our MEX-file
```

Next we explicitly unload the MEX function from memory (`clear all` would also do):

```
>> clear test2
>> [~,X] = inmem('-completenames')
X = 
    'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\slvnv\reqmgt\reqmgt.mexw64'
```

When we call the MEX function now, it is loaded and initialized once again (reproducing the same sequence of random numbers, because the generator is reset to the same default state):

```
>> test2
0.001251
```

Comment: fwiw you can lock your MEX-function in memory by using [`mexLock`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexlock.html) from the MEX API. Just don't forget to implement a mechanism that allows calling the corresponding `mexUnlock` (like a special input to indicate it, or registering a method using `mexAtExit`). Otherwise you won't be able to clear the MEX-file from memory unless you restart MATLAB itself..